# Serverless vs Serverless Cloud

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I built an API using Express which, while initially meant to be deployed to EC2, will now be deployed to Lambda. I looked into [Middy.js](https://middy.js.org/) initially, but there wasn't enough documentation on how to use it to build APIs.

Upon more research, I landed upon [Laconia](https://laconiajs.io/) and Serverless. The community around Serverless seems to be much bigger, but I probably wouldn't want to use it if it meant I had to get a subscription with them (not from the jump at least).

My understanding is that their tool is open source. However, looking at their [website](https://www.serverless.com/), I have not been able to differentiate which features are exclusive their cloud services vs their open source offering.

So, with all in mind, my question is:

- Is it possible to use Serverless without using Serverless Cloud?

Comment: Serverless is a concept, while Cloud is the location.  Ultimately, your code runs on servers somewhere, Serverless implies that this concern is not known or exposed to the user (the user being the person writing the code / deploying functions / lambdas).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all. My cloud environment is AWS, which I made note of in my question.

And by serverless, I clearly meant the serverless framework, something for which I provided a hyperlink for.

Here's what I'm asking: is it possible to use serverless-framework without serverless-cloud? serveless-cloud the offering, not cloud computing in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serverless Cloud is a SaaS product that Serverless Inc created and owns. It's in public beta right now (unclear about pricing). It helps you build, deploy, and run Serverless applications without worrying about AWS.

Serverless Framework is an open source project that Serverless Inc also maintains. It's free to use, but requires your own AWS account to run.

You're looking at two different products from the same company - one is free and [open source](https://github.com/serverless/serverless), the other is not. That's the difference. It's totally possible to use Serverless Framework without using Serverless Cloud.

(disclosure: I previously worked at Serverless Inc and have worked on both things)

Comment: Thank you for such an insightful answer.